# Apple Enterprise Push notification Invalid token

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I created the Push notification certificate (Production and Sandbox). I build my application with In house provisioning profile, and I upload to the server the Production certificate, but I got Invalid token error.
If I build my application with Development provisioning profile and upload the Sandbox certificate to the server I got the push notification.

What did I do wrong with the production certificate?

Comment: Both the development and production versions of the AppID need to have push notifications enabled on the Apple 'provisioning profile' website.

Comment: I see in the Development provisioning profile, that these are the enabled services: Associated Domains, Game Center, In-App Purchase, Push Notifications

Comment: And I see in the distribution provisioning profile the same as in the development provisioning profile

Comment: please check link it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568648/ios-production-push-notifications-invalid-token-from-apns-server