# Making Push Notifications on release build work again

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have released an app on iOS. Push notifications worked well for ad hoc distribution build. They won't work for released app. I am using PushWizard to send push notifications.
It has been a week and I have tried all of the below :

1. The signing identities are totally correct, I have signed the released app with the distribution certificate.
2. The provisioning profile that I have used for release has the correct non - wildcard app ID.
3. The certificate that is used for sending push on the server is the APN distribution certificate, though I have not replaced it after release of the new version of app, and I don't think that should be an issue.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong that is causing the APNs to send the "invalid token" error? I am using the same device that I used for dev and adhoc to test the release build. Perhaps, is that the problem ?

Comment: may be duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568648/ios-production-push-notifications-invalid-token-from-apns-server

Comment: no. Already tried the solutions in that answer and they do not help. Besides,  I verified everything that is there  in every answer specific to push notifications on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested your certificates (.pem) files to be able to connect to APN server using command line?

The most probable issue with 'invalid token' is related to certificate file and private key mismatch.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the input. How do I do that? Sorry I am not aware of the procedure